# Cannot add custom fields to a contact using Google App Scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to teach myself Google app scripts and I've run into a problem I can't figure out.  I have a script that gets data from a user form in google sheets and uses that data to create contact.

I am able to create contact and put it in the right group.

The trouble begins when I try and put a custom field on the contact and populate the custom field with data.

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'setLabel' of undefined
    at createPrimaryContact(Code:82:9)
    at createContacts(Code:27:24)
```

I've tried following along with the documentation at:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/custom-field without any success.

```js
function createPrimaryContact(contactsApp, data, group, groupName) {
  var contact = contactsApp.getContact(data.emailAddy);
  if (contact == null) {
    var contact = contactsApp.createContact(
      data.fName,
      data.lName,
      data.emailAddy
    );
    if (data.tel !== "") {
      contact.addPhone(ContactsApp.Field.MOBILE_PHONE, data.tel);
    }
    if (data.addy !== "") {
      var addyString =
        data.addy + " , " + data.cty + " , " + data.st + " " + data.postcode;
      contact.addAddress(ContactsApp.Field.HOME_ADDRESS, addyString);
    }
  }
  var group = contactsApp.getContactGroup(groupName);
  group.addContact(contact);
  var searchName = data.fName + " " + data.lName;
  var contacts = contactsApp.getContactsByName(searchName);
  var field = contacts[0].getCustomFields()[0];
  field.setLabel("Opportunity Name");  //this is line 82 that is generating the error mentioned above.
  field.setValue(data.oName);

  return { addyString };
}
```

I can't figure out what the problem is, even after many web searches later.

Can you see what I'm doing wrong ?

Any links or recommendations would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to `.getCustomFields()` and set a label, it implies that there are already custom fields present in your contact. If there are no custom fields available, the `.getCustomFields()` method will return an empty array. If you are trying to access the empty array as you do it here:

```
var field = contacts[0].getCustomFields()[0];
```

The `var field` will be equal to `undefined`, because there is no entry at position 0. That's why it is throwing the TypeError.

To solve this issue, just use the `.addCustomField(label, content)`method to create a custom field.

Applying it to your case:

```
var searchName = data.fName + " " + data.lName;
var contacts = contactsApp.getContactsByName(searchName);

contacts[0].addCustomField("Opportunity Name", data.oName)
```

Documentaion can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/contact#addCustomField(Object,Object)).